# Discord ping is reported as NaN

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a Discord Bot and I'm currently using an advanced command handler. I made a ping command, and after I was done with it the API ping displays NaN (Not a number) which is confusing because it displayed an actual number when I used a basic command handler. There were no error messages or anything just to clear up. Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

module.exports = {
 name: 'ping',
 description: 'check ping latency',
 execute(message, args) {
  //executes command

  if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_NICKNAMES')) {
   //checks if author has permission

   const ping = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp + ' ms'; //calculates dates

   embed //new embed
    .setTitle('Bot Latency:')
    .setDescription(`${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp} ms`) //bot latency
    .addField('API Latency', `${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`) //here is the problem
    .setFooter('For more details, visit discorddown')
    .setColor(0x008080);
   message.channel.send(embed);
   message.delete({
    timeout: 1000,
   });
  } else {
   message.delete({
    timeout: 1000,
   });
  }
 },
};
```

Comment: It isn't; you turned it into a string.

Comment: It might be because you are creating a new instance of the client. Instead of creating a *new* client, just use `message.client` whenever you need to access the existing client

Comment: Because I reproduced your code and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
module.exports = {
commands: ['ping'],
minArgs: 0,
maxArgs: 0,
callback: async(message, arguments, text) => {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    //const client = new Discord.Client();
    const msg = await message.channel.send("Pinging...");
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Pong!")
      .setAuthor(`${message.author.username}` , message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setDescription(
        `⌛ Latency is ${Math.floor(
          msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp
        )}ms\n⏲️ API Ping is ${Math.round(message.client.ws.ping)}`
      )
      .setColor('#fb644c');
    msg.edit(Embed);
    msg.edit("\u200b");
},  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer is a bit too code heavy. Could you please Elaborate what exactly your code has changed?